# How to get events on the same date when hover on event in full calendar library?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am trying to get the events on the same day when hovering on any event on the day. I don't know how to fetch the events ids on the same day. Please help me to get this done.

Thank you.

Comment: What did u tried until now? Any code?

Comment: So you are looking at a date with events scheduled on that day and when you hover over it you would like to catch the list of the events from that day? If I'm correct I would bind a moseover event and find the list of scheduled events in that element.  $(daysSelector).on("moseover", function(){ Find stuff in the DOM})

Comment: you can use https://fullcalendar.io/docs/clientEvents to get events which are currently displayed on the calendar - it will let you filter the results by any field including the date. If you add the date as an attribute somewhere in your popover (e.g. data-attribute, or a hidden field or something depending on your structure) then you can easily compare them.